# how to show smilys in yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I did smily functionality in my project it is working fine if i will put that variable outside the form, but it is not working with the form, Can anyone have solution how to show image in textarea, here is my code

```
<?php 
    echo $model->Description; (It shows me smily here but in active form it doesnt show)
    $form = ActiveForm::begin([
                'options' => ['enctype'=>'multipart/form-data','id'=>'ajax-post-form'
                ]
            ]); ?>

    <div>
        <?php echo $form->field($model, 'Description')->textarea(['rows' => 6]) ?>
    </div>  <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Comment: This is not trivial, you'll likely have to switch to an entire different kind of editor like https://www.tinymce.com/.

Comment: But we can't add editor for input type

Comment: Do you have any other solutions for that ?

Comment: There is no way to display graphics in a default `<textarea>`. The normal way (even for Facebook) is to show smileys in text form there, like `:)`

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to display graphics in a default `<textarea>`.
You Can only do this :
**HTML**

```
<textarea id="description" name="description"></textarea>   

<div id="emoticons">
    <a href="#" title=":)"><img alt=":)" border="0" src="http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/examples/markitup/sets/bbcode/images/emoticon-happy.png" /></a>
    <a href="#" title=":("><img alt=":(" border="0" src="http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/examples/markitup/sets/bbcode/images/emoticon-unhappy.png" /></a>
    <a href="#" title=":o"><img alt=":o" border="0" src="http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/examples/markitup/sets/bbcode/images/emoticon-surprised.png" /></a>
</div>
```

**JAVA SCRIPT**

```
$('#emoticons a').click(function() {
    var smiley = $(this).attr('title');
    ins2pos(smiley, 'description');
});

function ins2pos(str, id) {
   var TextArea = document.getElementById(id);
   var val = TextArea.value;
   var before = val.substring(0, TextArea.selectionStart);
   var after = val.substring(TextArea.selectionEnd, val.length);
   TextArea.value = before + str + after;
}
```

[Demo Link](http://jsfiddle.net/JVDES/13/)

Answer (score 1):

You can render emojis in a textearea, as any other character defined in the unicode specification.

Index: http://www.unicode.org/emoji/charts/index.html

List of emojis: http://www.unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html

In the list of emojis, you can refer to the column "code" to know the unicode value, or copy & paste the displayed value in the column "brow." if necessary (I think you should close your eyes about the other colorful columns).

You will need to use a font that can display these glyphs. Using this technic, only **monochromatic** emojis/smileys can be displayed, but it does not require any hack of the `textarea`, it is just text.

Moreover you will be able to just save this text with your favorite UTF flavor.

For display purposes, you may want to convert the unicode character to an image. Of course that's possible (outside a textarea) but not mandatory.

Hope it helps